# Replace file explorer / Intercept opening of file explorer

Tags: windows, windows-10, explorer

is there a way to intercept file explorer open requests?
For example if I press Win+E or in programs when I press a button open in file explorer or double-clicking a folder on the desktop and whatever possibilities are out there.

The reason why I am asking is that I am developing a little file explorer for Win-10 and I wanted to know if it's possible to replace the windows provided explorer.exe.

I hope you can imagine what I mean. Thanks in advance.